# How to hide jwt access token?

Tags: php, node.js, express, jwt

My app should hide access token from users that use app, how can I accomplish that?

I am using express.js for api...

Now I am able on login to generate token like this:

```
var userInstance;

app.post("/login/user" ,function(req,res) {
    var cred = _.pick(req.body, "email", "password");

    db.user.loginAuth(cred.email, cred.password)
    .then(function (user) {
       userInstance = user;
       return db.token.create({
        token: user.generateToken("auth")
       });

    })
    .then(function(token) {
        res.send({
            token: token.token,
            user: userInstance
        });
    })
    .catch(function() {
        res.status(401).send();
    });


});
```

I need to create for example php script that will use api and token will not been compromised

Comment: @Federico - JWT is a pretty well-known spec in its own right, and might be a better fit for his needs than OAuth2. He's not reinventing anything (unless he's trying to write a JWT library himself, in which case, for the love of god stop and use an established one).

Comment: https://www.toptal.com/web/cookie-free-authentication-with-json-web-tokens-an-example-in-laravel-and-angularjs read this man

Comment: Yes it's more flexible when I write my own. @Gandalf the White He use AngularJS to retrieve tokens which mean user can read tokens from browser...

Comment: If the User really wants he can retrieve whatever as a data you send to him/her, whether it be an mobile application or web app. Therefore you need to code in such a way that even if the user can see your client side data it wont hamper your security.

Comment: your access token will be visible no matter where you hide it as you have to send the access token in request header for jwt to authorize your request which can be easily read by user using any browser dev tools. Assuming you only allow access to authorized users, you should be able to control what user can do and cannot, do not expose api endpoints that can do any harm , set your jwt token to have a decent expire time after which user has to get auth again you should be fine then

Comment: My goal is to backend of app get some information from API, but I don't wont user of app have access to API... Is possible to accomplished that?

Comment: @Vladimir-  If your backend, ie php, is pulling info from the API, don't expose the token to the browser. Php gets the token, stores it perhaps in user session, hits api with the token and returns fetched data to the browser.